# Registering endpoint in Spring-WS

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

We are trying to build a web service here. We want the service to be available at `/axis2/services/SmsNotificationService​`. The operation that will be invoked is `notifySmsDeliveryReceipt`. The following is Spring's endpoint.

```
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.annotation.Action;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

@Endpoint
public class SmsNotificationService {

    @Action("http://axis2/services/SmsNotificationService")
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "notifySmsDeliveryReceipt", namespace = "http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Element handleNotifyReceipt(@RequestPayload Element root) {
        String correlator = root.getChild("correlator").getValue();
        Element deliveryStatusElement = root.getChild("deliveryStatus");
        String address = deliveryStatusElement.getChild("address").getValue();
        String deliveryStatus = deliveryStatusElement.getChild("deliveryStatus").getValue();

        System.out.println("correlator: " + correlator);
        System.out.println("address: " + address);
        System.out.println("deliveryStatus: " + deliveryStatus);

        String s="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\u2018http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\u2019 xmlns:loc=\u2018http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local\u2019>\n"+
                "<soapenv:Header/>\n"+
                "<soapenv:Body>\n"+
                "<loc:notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse/>\n"+
                "</soapenv:Body>\n"+
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        SAXBuilder sxBuild = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc;
        Element returnRoot = null;
        try {
            doc = sxBuild.build(new StringReader(s));
            returnRoot = doc.getRootElement();
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnRoot;
    }
}
```

The client will invoke the service using this XML.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=‘http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/’ xmlns:v3=‘http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v3_1’ xmlns:loc=‘http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local’>
  <soapenv:Header>
    <v3:NotifySOAPHeader>
      <spId>600002</spId>
    </v3:NotifySOAPHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <loc:notifySmsDeliveryReceipt>
      <loc:correlator>123</loc:correlator>
      <loc:deliveryStatus>
        <address>tel:+86123</address>
        <deliveryStatus>DeliveredToTerminal</deliveryStatus>
      </loc:deliveryStatus>
    </loc:notifySmsDeliveryReceipt>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The service needs to return this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=‘http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/’ xmlns:loc=‘http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local’>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <loc:notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Tomcat's access log registers a service call but the remote caller received an error:

```
`xxx.xx.xxx.x - - [13/May/2016:13:43:43 +0630] "POST /axis2/services/SmsNotificationService​ HTTP/1.1" 404 -`
```

Catalina's log shows the following:

```
13-May-2016 13:42:32.459 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.afterPropertiesSet Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
13-May-2016 13:42:32.487 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2e8571ab: defining beans [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.Dom4jPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.XomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
13-May-2016 13:42:32.764 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
13-May-2016 13:42:32.784 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'spring-ws': initialization completed in 2448 ms
13-May-2016 13:43:43.774 WARNING [http-nio-8088-exec-8] org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local}notifySmsDeliveryReceipt]
```

The problem may lie in the endpoint not being registered by Spring-WS.

Does anyone have any idea how to register an endpoint and declare an operation using Spring-WS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using spring WS, then you should define

servlet mapping in web.xml file

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>  
        <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>classpath:springws-config.xml</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/axis2/services/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

MessageDispatcherServlet scans all beans of Wsdl11Definition in classpath and publish them.
Then you need to create a spring configuration file :

springws-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="some.package.SmsNotificationService"/>
    <sws:annotation-driven />
    <!-- you can use static-wsdl OR dynamic-wsdl here -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct. The service is now throwing 500 errors.